# What is an alternative (or the correct way) of calling a PHP function from with a str_replace() (All contained within a function)?

Tags: php, function, str-replace

My question is basically whether or not what I am trying to do is even possible. I am either doing something incorrectly, or I am dreaming too big... (Insert unprofessional php designer disclaimer here).

I am creating an automatic emailing system. I have the layout of my email stored in a text file. Information that I wanted to be written dynamically is represented by what I am calling tags (i.e. [DATE], [CUSTNAME], [MESSAGE]...).

When an email is created and delivered, variables are passed to a function from my index page, I simply include the text file while replacing my tags with dynamic content. This works beautifully for me, up until I wanted to beef up content in the newsletter. Now I want to add in a section that is called from an independent function. This caused my Email function to actually display the content from the called function 3 times right there rather than complete the function of shooting the email and redirect as necessary.

My code (contained inside a function) before updating (working for me):

```
$EmailBodyTEXT = addslashes($EmailBody);
$EmailBody = 
str_replace('[YEAR]', date(Y),
str_replace('[SUBJECT]', $EmailSubject, 
str_replace('[DATE]', date('l, F j, Y'), 
str_replace('[MESSAGE]', $EmailBody, file_get_contents($url . 'newsletter_BLANK.txt')))));
```

My code after updating (fail):

```
$EmailBodyTEXT = addslashes($EmailBody);
$EmailBody = 
str_replace('[YEAR]', date(Y),
str_replace('[SUBJECT]', $EmailSubject, 
str_replace('[DATE]', date('l, F j, Y'), 
str_replace('[MESSAGE]', $EmailBody,
str_replace('[PHOTOSTREAM]', PhotoStream(CUST), file_get_contents($url . 'newsletter_BLANK.txt'))))));
```

For what it is worth, I tried to 'load' the second function in a $variable and replaced the function call with the variable, exact same result, as I anticipated.

How should I call this function to not 'execute' on the spot, but continue with the process of the containing function, which would pass this content into the email in the process of creation and delivery? Am I simply incorrect in thinking there is a way to load a function from the str_replace process? Is there a more obvious way of trying to do this (basically a mail merge) function?

Please let me know your thoughts and if more code is needed from me.

Here is the PhotoStream():

```
function PhotoStream($DispTo) {
global $url, $uri, $urp, $locurl;

if(empty($DispTo)) { echo 'unconfigured'; continue; } else {

if($DispTo == 'CUST') { $DispTo = urlencode('$redacted'); } else { $DispTo = '$redacted'; }

}

if($getPics = mysql_query("SELECT pid, px, title FROM photos ORDER BY pubdate DESC LIMIT 6")) {

echo '<fieldset><div id="wrapNL">';

while($gPics = mysql_fetch_array($getPics)) {

$pid = $gPics{'pid'};
$pex = $gPics{'px'};
$ptl = $gPics{'title'};

echo '<div id="pthumbs"><a href="' . $uri . $DispTo . '&PID=' . $pid . $locurl . '">';
echo '<img src="' . $urp . 'uploads/' . $pid . '.' . $pex . '" alt="' . $ptl . '" title="' . $ptl . '">';
echo '</a></div>';

}

echo '</div></fieldset>';

}

}
```

Comment: What does your `PhotoStream` function do? Does it echo anything, or return it?

Comment: You can just pass arrays to `str_replace` 's 1st and 2nd parameters instead of chaining `str_replace` calls. For example: `str_replace(array('[YEAR]', '[SUBJECT]'), array(date('Y'), $EmailSubject), $EmailBody)`.

Comment: I added the PhotoStream(). it does echo.

Comment: It should `return` instead of `echo`, since you want to use it's return value in `str_replace`.

Comment: There's the problem. Either return the generated HTML as a string, or catch the echo's into a variable using an [output buffer](http://php.net/ob_get_contents) and then use that variable in your str_replace.

Comment: Also: You're using `$EmailBody` in your `str_replace` while still assigning to it. In your 2nd example, the `str_replace` for `PhotoStream` gets executed first and replaces that tag. Then the `[message]` tag gets replaced with the body itself (which still contains placeholder), then the `[date]`, `[subject]` and `[year]` tags each operate on that version (hence the repititions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are overcomplicating this.

If you want to replace multiple  alues within a string you can uae the **strtr** function. It takes 2 arguments, the first is the string to replace the valies into and the second is an associate array of keys representing replacements and there values representing the value to replace them with.

Try something similar to the following:

```
<?php

$emailBody = strtr($emailBodyRaw, array(
    '[TOKEN]' => 'token value',
    '[ANOTHER]' => 'another value',
    //More replacements here
));
```

Your more complex replacements can be done outside of this snippet and substitued in as a single variable.

---

EDIT: You will want to update your PhotoStream function to **return** a value rather than echo it aswell. You can always echo whats returned if required somewhere else within your app

---

EDIT 2: Capturing PhotoStream echo output in a variable

Using a method known as **output buffering** you can use your PhotoStream function in its current state by doing something similar to the following:

```
<?php

ob_start();
PhotoStream($DispTo)
$photo = ob_get_clean();
ob_end_clean()

$emailBody = strtr($emailBodyRaw, array(
    '[PHOTO]' => $photo
    //More replacements here
));
```

Doing this you capture what PhotoStream echo's and store it in a variable.

To use the function directly in the replacement array you will have to refactor it to return the html rather than echo it.

Comment: I think you are probably right... but would I be able to replace [ATAG] with => aFunction()?

Comment: That would work fine, aslong as you return a value from your function rather than echo it out.

Comment: Updated my answer to show how you can capture the echo output of your PhotoStream function and use it as a replacement. Hope that helps!

Comment: You sir just made my day! Thank you so much! That works really well for me.

Comment: With regards to the output buffer method, don't forget to *end* the output buffer using `ob_end_clean()` after getting the contents. If you keep it open, you may run into problems later in your code.